# Error while building Cordova project in Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I'm trying to build a cordova project in visual studio 2015 and I'm getting the following error: '**Use of const in strict mode.**' I've been stuck in this problem for quite a while now.

This is my build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ChemTreatApp, Configuration: Debug iOS ------
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 5.3.3 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: D:\Patient 360\Code\ChemTreatApp\bld\iOS\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: D:\Patient 360\Code\ChemTreatApp\bin\iOS\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: prepare
1>  ------    platform: iOS
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: ios
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: ChemTreatApp
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: D:\Patient 360\Code\ChemTreatApp
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\safan.allauddin\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Adding platform: ios
1>  SyntaxError: C:\Users\safan.allauddin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\cordova\5.3.3\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tough-cookie\node_modules\ip-regex\index.js:3
1>  const v4 = '(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])(?:\\.(?:25[0-
1>  ^^^^^
1>  Use of const in strict mode.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

My cordova CLI version is 5.3.3, my NPM version 6.7.0 and my node version is 11.10.0.

Thanks.